# Connect with VNC to RPI 3B+ via Bluetooth

Tags: pi-3b+, bluetooth, vnc, data-transfer

I want to do **VNC via Bluetooth between my Raspberry pi 3b+ and an android phone**.

Some forums **say that bluetooth technology is so slow** to connect VNC via a DUN network, but I was doing some research about bluetooth and this has good speed for this purpose.

[image: Bluetooth speed table]

Via: https://merehead.com/blog/top-difference-between-bluetooth-4-2-and-bluetooth-5-0/

The reason to do this via bluetooth is because I don't want to use a display for my RPI, I want to transport it and check it with my phone.
Bluetooth seems the best option because I can be connected to an access point to internet via wifi (In my house, work, restaurant, etc) and connected to my RPI via bluetooth (Plug and play, Sort of).

If this is not possible I want to know why and **what is the real speed** of this technology to do networking and handle big loads of data.

Comment: Very interesting but I don't believe that anyone has already measured it. So it's up to you to test it and give it to the community ;-) If you get stuck with some details you can ask about it.

Comment: I'll test it in the weekend, then publish the results.